Solving $\left\lfloor \sin \left( x\right) \right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \sin \left( \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right) \right\rfloor =1$
I've created this equation $\left\lfloor \sin \left( x\right) \right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \sin \left( \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right) \right\rfloor =1$ for real numbers $x$. I've found a complicated formula for the solutions and I'm not sure about it since I found it hard to simplify it.
The solution I've found is :
$x\in \left( \underset{k\in\mathbb{Z}
}{\bigcup }\left( \left[ 2k\pi ,\left( 1+2k\right) \pi \right] \diagup
\left\{ \frac{\pi }{2}+2k\pi \right\} \right) \right) \cap \left( \underset{l\in
\mathbb{Z}
}{\bigcup }\left[ \left\lfloor \left( -1+2l\right) \pi \right\rfloor
+1,\left\lfloor 2l\pi \right\rfloor +1\right[ \right) $
It seems I've missed something, since this I've simplified it to :
$x\in \underset{k\in\mathbb{Z}}{\bigcup }\left[ 2k\pi ,\left\lfloor 2k\pi \right\rfloor +1\right[ $
But this last formula don't show that $\frac{\pi }{2}$ is a solution. So any help please ?

HINT: Try graphing the function $f(x) = \lfloor \sin (x) \rfloor - \lfloor \sin (\lfloor x \rfloor)\rfloor$. And I'd suggest you do it by hand rather than relying on some software to graph it for you. This should provide a good intution for the expression.

I simplified it to $x\in \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\bigcup }\left[ 2k\pi ,\left\lfloor 2k\pi \right\rfloor +1\right[ $ which seems to be in accordance with the graph.

$x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a solution, but does not belong to any interval $[2k\pi ,\left\lfloor 2k\pi \right\rfloor +1[$

If you want people to check your solution, you need to include your solution - not just the result. Also do that in the post, not in the comments.

I will post it @Sil

Note that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is also not in any set $\left[ 2k\pi ,\left( 1+2k\right) \pi \right] \setminus
\left{ \frac{\pi }{2}+2k\pi \right}$, so already the first characterization is incorrect.

Your original formula is the intersection of where $\lfloor\sin x\rfloor = 0$ with where $\lfloor(\sin \lfloor x\rfloor)\rfloor = -1$, but the difference is also $1$ when $\lfloor\sin x\rfloor = 1$ and $\lfloor(\sin \lfloor x\rfloor)\rfloor = 0$, which you haven't accounted for. Since you left it out at the start, it will still be missing in the simplification.

Thank you so much @PaulSinclair

Your solution is close to correct, but it's hard to tell where you made a mistake since you did not provide the derivation. Anyway, here is a complete solution.
Let $A=\left\lfloor \sin  x\right\rfloor$ and $B=\left\lfloor \sin \left( \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right) \right\rfloor$. Since $A,B$ are both integers and $\sin x\in[-1,1]$, $A-B=1$ is only possible if either $(A,B)=(1,0)$ or $(A,B)=(0,-1)$. Let's tackle these separately.
Case 1: $(A,B)=(1,0)$
Clearly $A=1$ holds if and only if $\sin x = 1$, and so $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$. We will show that for all such $x$, we have $B=0$. To prove this, we will use the following observation.
Lemma. Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $2k\pi\leq\lfloor 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \rfloor<2k\pi+\pi$.
Proof. Both inequalities are trivial if we realize $1<\frac{\pi}{2}<\pi$. $\square$
As a consequence, $\sin( \lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \rfloor) \geq 0$. So, unless $\sin( \lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \rfloor)=1$, we have $\lfloor \sin( \lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \rfloor) \rfloor=0$. However, $\sin( \lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \rfloor)=1$ cannot occur: as $\sin x=1$ iff $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi$ for some integer $m$, i.e. $\lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \rfloor=\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi$, but then $\pi$ would be rational, impossible. So indeed $$B=\left\lfloor \sin\left( \left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \right\rfloor\right) \right\rfloor=0.$$
Solution of this case is therefore $$x\in\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \left\{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right\}.$$
Case 2: $(A,B)=(0,-1)$
Using same argument as before, $A=\left\lfloor \sin  x\right\rfloor=0$ if and only if $2k\pi\leq x<2k\pi+\pi$ and $x\neq 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some integer $k$. To have also $B=-1$, we must have $\sin \left( \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right)<0$. This can happen if and only if $2l\pi-\pi< \lfloor x \rfloor<2l\pi$ for some integer $l$. To summarize, this case has a solution $x$ iff there exist integers $k,l$ such that
$$
2k\pi\leq x<2k\pi+\pi,x\neq 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\\
2l\pi-\pi< \lfloor x \rfloor<2l\pi.
$$
If $k \geq l+1$, then $x\geq 2l\pi+\pi$ and it contradicts $\lfloor x \rfloor <2l\pi$. Similarly $l \geq k+1$ is impossible. Hence $k=l$. Notice also that $\lfloor x \rfloor <2k\pi$ implies $x<2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}<2k\pi+\pi$. In particular, we can drop the explicit condition $x\neq 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$. Similarly, $2k\pi \leq x$ implies $2k\pi -\pi<\lfloor x \rfloor$. So, we have reduced this case to
$$
2k\pi\leq x\\
\lfloor x \rfloor < 2k\pi\\
$$
Clearly $k=0$ does not give a solution. If $k\neq 0$, then $2k\pi$ is not an integer and the above is equivalent to $2k\pi \leq x <\lfloor 2k\pi \rfloor+1$. So, the solution of this case is $$x \in \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}} [2k\pi, \lfloor 2k\pi \rfloor+1).$$
Final solution
We have shown the complete solution is given by
$$
x\in \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \left\{2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right\} \cup \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}} [2k\pi,\lfloor 2k\pi \rfloor+1) .
$$

$k=0$ is not allowed in the second union ?

Correct, because $2k\pi\leq x$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor < 2k\pi$ has no solution for $k=0$. You can also check, for example, that $x=0$ is not a solution.

Thank you so much @Sil
